# Decomposition of cyclotomic extensions with totally real components

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$ be a cyclotomic extension. For which values of $n$ is it the case that this extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ decomposes as a tower  $K\subset L\subset \mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$ of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that one of the $[K:L]$ and $[L:\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)]$ is equal to $2$ and the other is totally real? My own guess is that it can never be decomposed in this way, but do not see how to prove this. You can also assume that $n$ is a prime number if it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by a "direct sum" of extensions? For any fields $E$ and $F$, the ring $E\oplus F$ is not a field.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. It was totally wrong in the previous format.

Comment: What's wrong with $K=\Bbb{Q}$ and 
$$L=\Bbb{Q}(\xi_n)\cap\Bbb{R}=\Bbb{Q}(\cos2pi/n)?$$
Here $[\Bbb{Q}(\xi_n):L]=2$ and $L$ is totally real, because the conjugates of $\cos2\pi/n$ are $\cos2\pi m/n$, with $m<n,\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, in fact every cyclotomic field is a 
CM field.